# Access elements inside iframe using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to access the elements of an iframe, on a webpage that was made using the Wix Site Builder, using PowerPoint VBA.

I tried everything I found on Google and also other webpages but I can't figure it out. Most common errors are "Automation error" when I try to use `contentDocument` and "Access Denied" when I try to use `contentWindow`.

```
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.navigate "https://pptgamespt.wixsite.com/mppp/tests2"
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
Pausecode (2)
objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementById("input").Value = "some value"
```

I'm trying to change the value of the input with the id "input" that is inside the iframe, which has no class or id. The code above is the last one I tried that throws the error "Automation error".

Answer (score 0):

I think you will hit same origin policy problems for IE. You can grab the src of the iframe and navigate on to that

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SendInfo()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://pptgamespt.wixsite.com/mppp/tests2"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .Navigate2 ie.document.querySelector("iframe").src

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.querySelector("#input").Value = "Bob"
        .document.querySelector("#send").Click

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Using selenium basic and chrome to get around same origin policy problem. After installing selenium basic a reference to selenium type library must be added vbe > tools > references > selenium type library

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub EnterInfo()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "https://pptgamespt.wixsite.com/mppp/tests2"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        .SwitchToFrame .FindElementByCss("iframe")
        Do
        Loop While .FindElementsByCss("#input").Count = 0
        .FindElementByCss("#input").SendKeys "tada"
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is that I need the webpage and the iframe at the same time. They will "work together".

Comment: How is that so?

Comment: I want to send and get information from the Wix database, to do that I will put a code on the website that will send the text inside an input. Before that I want to make sure I can change the value of the input wich didn't work for the Wix Input element, so I decided to use an HTML iframe. I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Is there a way I can attempt to replicate the set of steps you want and an expected outcome I can test against?

Comment: At the moment I have answered the question as stated so worth clarifying this additional step.

Comment: I already knew what you told me. My only problem is accessing the iframe inside the webpage. So I think you don't need to replicate, just help me try to access the iframe inside the webpage. I think Wix has secured the webpage so you can't just change things on the wegpage and use Bots...

Comment: You knew what I told you? It is a same origin policy problem in relation to IE. I will add a script using selenium vba and chrome which shows you can access as a bot when you don't have same origin IE problem.

Comment: Oh ok, I got it. IE has that policy... Is there a way of bypassing it in PowerPoint VBA using IE?

Comment: Not as far as I know. The best ways are as shown above or look for an API. There are some tricks for bypassing same origin policy with IE but I haven’t succeeded with the libraries available in MS products.